# Extracting information from .ab1 file with Bioconductor/sangerseqR package

Tags: r, sequence, bioconductor

I wish to extract information from a .ab1 file. Specifically, the amplitude of primary and secondary base call peaks - P1AM.1 and P2AM.1

```
library(sangerseqR)
x=read.abif(file.choose())
x@data$P1AM.1
```

gives me output NULL. Any help regarding what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Check if the feature is present in your data: `names(x@data)` or `grep("P1AM.1", names(x@data))`. Probably not, which is why it returns NULL.–  JTT1 hour ago

Comment: Oh thanks! turns out it isn't. Can I export it to some other format for this particular information or there is nothing I can do about it ?

Comment: Do you know the Genetic Analyzer version that created the file in thr first plase? Isn't the P1AM.1 tag very specific to 3500 series of machines? It might be that sangerseqR works only with this version of the tagging, but I don't have extensive test material to verify this. Can you generate the basecalls for your data or not?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure how to generate basecalls for data. I have only just started looking into .ab1 files. So I am not quite sure about your first question either.

Comment: Vignette for the sangerseR package should help with the specifics, such as how to generate the basecalls. Other than that, if the tag is not in the data, and it is absolutely needed, there is very little to do, except to generate the data again. Hope you find a solution!